# spark-submit giving Invalid syntax error message on Windows 10 with Python 2.7, Java 1.8

Tags: python, apache-spark

This is a question on Spark installed as standalone in Windows 10.  I have installed Spark and the related hadoop classses in my system. I am learning Spark, 
After I start Spark interactive shell by running in cmd `"C:\Spark\bin\pyspark"`
it starts

```
Spark version 1.6.1
```

However I am not able to run spark-submit

The command:

```
C:\Spark\bin\spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master local \
                          C:\Spark\lib\spark-examples*.jar 10
```

gives

> "Syntax error: Invalid Syntax"

error message. I get the same error when i try to submit any python file as well.

I have installed Java 8 and python 2.7 in my system.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should run spark-submit in command line instead of in spark-shell or pyspark.